# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 Shows up When Trying to Convert String into Int in Python

Tags: python

Im trying to setup my dataset for my linear regression. I can't simply fit the dates in the LinReg model because it needs a numerical value or an int. So Im trying to use `int()` to convert the string into int. But I get an error - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

The code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/Customers.csv')

print(int(df.date[0]))
```

Comment: Try to print df.date[0] without conversion. What does it print?

Comment: r u sure the date (like ’01/31/2021’) may be parsed to int (like `10`)? Seems like there will be a couple of excessive slashes (or dashes) in it :)

Comment: @FedorIvanov It prints 1/1/2022

Comment: @madbird yes there are dashes

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#int and https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 2):

Try parsing date as Timestamp and using toordinal on that:

```py
In [14]: import io, pandas as pd
    ...: 
    ...: text = "date\n01/31/2021\n"
    ...: buff = io.StringIO(text)
    ...: df = pd.read_csv(buff, converters={"date": pd.Timestamp})
    ...: ts = df.date[0]

In [15]: ts
Out[15]: Timestamp('2021-01-31 00:00:00')

In [16]: ts.toordinal()
Out[16]: 737821

In [17]:
```

[Source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html):

> datetime.toordinal() is a simple method used to manipulate the objects of DateTime class. It returns proleptic Gregorian ordinal of the date, where January 1 of year 1 has ordinal 1. The function returns the ordinal value for the given DateTime object.
>
> If January 1 of year 1 has ordinal number 1 then, January 2 year 1 will have ordinal number 2, and so on.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't use the buff parameter as I am not yet familiar with how that works and why do i need it. And Im not sure if using the example text = "date..." is dynamic. So I used converters in my read_csv line and used toordinal(). And I got the same result!

Thanks! Wouldnt have had any idea if it werent for this.

Comment: I needed the buff parameter because I did not want to create a file to read csv from. You may just skip buffer-related part, and leave ‘data/Customers.csv’ as is. The major part is regarding conversions + toordinal